# Convert Android.mk files to build.gradle files

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a mixed code base (C++ and Java) and I am planning to use Android Studio as my IDE and convert my existing Android.mk files to build.gradle files.

Is there a way to convert them easily? If not, are there good tutorials / blogs/ documentation that can help me get started on this?

Comment: You need to specify which gradle plugin version you're targetting, since the answer will depend on that. Note that with the latest plugin, [you can keep using your old make files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378808/how-to-properly-use-ndk-build-in-android-studio-2-2-preview-1/37765067#37765067).

Comment: @Michael. Thanks Michael. I am new to this and I still need to understand this better.I downloaded the sample HelloJNI code and say I want to build my code base using that as the base. It uses gradle-experimenta;0.7.0. Also, what if .mk files are not supported in the future and then we will have to move to gradle anyway. I am not totally sure here as to which is the best way to go. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.1.2 and I also have gradle 2.10 installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting android ndk build files to gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479340/converting-android-ndk-build-files-to-gradle)